# Change value of a variable based on another variable's value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a variable which is @State and I receive a @Binding value from that. I want to have a variable that changes the color based on the value of my @State variable.

Example

```
@State var great: String = ""
var bkgColor: Color
bkgColor = Color.red         //if great == "1"
bkgColor = Color.green       // if great == "0"
bkgColor = Color.gray        // if great == "" or default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed property, like:

```
@State var great: String = ""
var bkgColor: Color {
   switch(great) {
      case "1":
        return Color.red
      case "0":
        return Color.green
      default:
        return Color.gray
   }
}
```